# Graphically showing the nearby scanned Bluetooth devices, like below

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, bluetooth

I am working in an application in which I need to scan nearby Bluetooth devices and show them in a graphical manner like below screen. I am able to scan the devices and the problem is to show them and to draw lines between the devices and scan button.

[image]

Is there any library available in android to achieve this type of screen.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dvdciri/daggraph this library might help, especially the linked node graph

Using the following code to get the previously connected Bluetooth devices

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```